# Excel Max only when Formula output greater than Zero?

Tags: excel

I have the formula below which has three If statements, I would like to add a MAX function, but only if the output of the formula is > 0. Any help is appreciated.

```
=IF($A$1=$E$3,P23,IF($K$1=$E$4,P23,IF($K$1=$E$5,P23,"0")))
```

Comment: What do you want to output if the function is <=0?

Comment: @Rob . If the output is 0 Then 0

Comment: Can you be more specific. where does the MAX come in? If the original formula returns 100 or 1000 how should that change?

Comment: On a side note, your formula can be simplified this way: `= IF(OR($A$1=$E$3,$K$1=$E$4,$K$1=$E$5),"0")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(IF($A$1=$E$3,P23,IF($K$1=$E$4,P23,IF($K$1=$E$5,P23,"0"))) >0 ,MAX(Whatever...),0)
```

I test the value of the function to see if it is greater than zero.

If it is, I return the value of the MAX function (you don't say what you want to find the maximum of).

If it isn't, I return zero as requested.

Comment: Please explain why you suggest this change.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for the help, but for some reason, I cant make it work. If you try the formula below, it should be zero but for some reason it always returns one. =IF(IF(5=3,5,IF(6=4,7,IF(3=5,8,"0")))>0,1,0)

Comment: Replace the "0" with just 0